# Two solr threads trying to load core at startup time

Tags: solr, lucene

My solr installation has only one core, and i have noticed that when i restart the service, two threads are trying to load the core. Inevitably, one of them fails, and I see error like these:

```
filesearch: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
```

and:

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this virtual machine: /local/var/solr/shard1/mysearch/data/index/write.lock
```

Here is the startup log:-

`(main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server jetty-9.3.14.v20161028
(main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter  ___      _       Welcome to Apache Solr™ version 6.6.1-SNAPSHOT 1a390a91b5b658150478e6fc3c43381bedd3c6d3 - niqbal - 2017-08-09 10:31:27
(main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter / __| ___| |_ _   Starting in standalone mode on port 8984
(main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter \__ \/ _ \ | '_|  Install dir: /local/bin/solr6/latest_solr
(main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter |___/\___/_|_|    Start time: 2017-08-25T20:04:38.231Z
(main) [   ] o.a.s.s.StartupLoggingUtils Property solr.log.muteconsole given. Muting ConsoleAppender named CONSOLE
(main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Using system property solr.solr.home: /local/etc/solr/shard1
(main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading container configuration from /local/etc/solr/shard1/solr.xml
(main) [   ] o.a.s.u.UpdateShardHandler Creating UpdateShardHandler HTTP client with params: socketTimeout=600000&connTimeout=60000&retry=true
(main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Found 1 core definitions underneath /local/etc/solr/shard1
(main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Cores are: [mysearch]
(coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.u.SolrIndexConfig IndexWriter infoStream solr logging is enabled
(coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrConfig Using Lucene MatchVersion: 6.5.2
(qtp761960786-29) [   ] o.a.s.c.TransientSolrCoreCacheDefault Allocating transient cache for 2147483647 transient cores
(main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started @1225ms
(coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema [mysearch] Schema name=local
WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Field name_token is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (7)
WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Field name_shingle is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (5)
WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Field name_sort is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (7)
(coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Loaded schema local/1.5 with uniqueid field id
INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Creating SolrCore 'mysearch' using configuration from instancedir /local/etc/solr/shard1/mysearch, trusted=true
INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrCore solr.RecoveryStrategy.Builder
INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [[mysearch] ] Opening new SolrCore at [/local/etc/solr/shard1/mysearch], dataDir=[/local/etc/solr/shard1/mysearch/data/]
INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.r.XSLTResponseWriter xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=5
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.u.SolrIndexConfig IndexWriter infoStream solr logging is enabled
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrConfig Using Lucene MatchVersion: 6.5.2
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema [mysearch] Schema name=local
WARN  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Field name_token is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (7)
WARN  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Field name_shingle is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (5)
WARN  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Field name_sort is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (7)
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema Loaded schema local/1.5 with uniqueid field id
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Creating SolrCore 'mysearch' using configuration from instancedir /local/etc/solr/shard1/mysearch, trusted=true
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrCore solr.RecoveryStrategy.Builder
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [[mysearch] ] Opening new SolrCore at [/local/etc/solr/shard1/mysearch], dataDir=[/local/etc/solr/shard1/mysearch/data/]
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.r.XSLTResponseWriter xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=5
INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.u.CommitTracker Hard AutoCommit: disabled
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.u.CommitTracker Hard AutoCommit: disabled
INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.u.CommitTracker Soft AutoCommit: disabled
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.u.CommitTracker Soft AutoCommit: disabled
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [mysearch]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@3f24b393
INFO  (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for: solr.core.mysearch
ERROR (qtp761960786-31) [   x:mysearch] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mysearch]
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:935)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1331)`

Comment: First, update your Solr to a released version - building from trunk _can_ give weird issues. Are you running a single node setup? Are  you sharing the directories across multiple instances? Is there a zombie process hanging around somewhere?

Comment: @MatsLindh i don't know why you feel that I am building from trunk. This is branch 6_6, which was released few weeks ago. I also posted this issue on solr users community and it seems that others are also noticing this issue now: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-6-6-1-Lock-held-by-this-virtual-machine-td4352160.html

Comment: Sure; HEAD of the branch. That still means that there are potential issues that haven't been qa-ed or released yet, so if you build at the wrong time, stuff might break in weird places. Good to see that it got attention on solr-user!